# Does duplicate machine SID cause problems with Remote Desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1, sysprep, sid

I am currently working on a Windows 8.1 image for Dell Venue Pro 11 and have been having some issues with generalizing the image with SysPrep.

I am not planning on placing the tablets in a domain, however if you were to login from such a tablet with a non-unique SID to a domain server using remote desktop and another person would do this as well (same SID, same server, different domain account) - could this cause any issues?

Comment: What's the real question here? Whether having duplicate SID's is an issue or whether or not you should continue using sysprep?

Comment: Looking at it, I think it's the first one, so I tried editing it down to just the essence of that question to avoid it being closed, for now.

Answer (score 6):

Sysprep isn't needed to prevent duplicate SIDs.

> The more I thought about it, the more I became convinced that machine SID duplication – having multiple computers with the same machine SID – doesn’t pose any problem, security or otherwise. I took my conclusion to the Windows security and deployment teams and no one could come up with a scenario where two systems with the same machine SID, whether in a Workgroup or a Domain, would cause an issue. At that point the decision to retire NewSID became obvious.

The Machine SID Duplication Myth (and Why Sysprep Matters)
http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx